# How to store login and logout time in database using c# window Application?

Tags: c#

I am new to this .net Program and I am in bit confusion,
I want to store the Login and logout time in database and i have tried the code for login in one form,

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
labelLoginTime.Text = dt.ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);                       

con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Table(LoginTime) values('"+dt+"')",con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

here I set Allow nulls is true to LogoutTime column in the databse
once I login in the window, the next form opens i.e, logout form 
once i click logout button in the second form it stores only Logout time in the next row
and showing login value is Null in the same line.
Here I want to show both login and logout time should be displayed in the same row.
Please Help me to solve this.
the code for logout is

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;
labelLogut.Text = dt2.ToString();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);


con.Open();
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into Table(LogoutTime) values('"+dt2+"')",con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Sorry for the long Explaination, Please help me to display login and logout time in single row in Database.Thanks in Advnce!!!

Comment: What do you want to display when the program crashes and only has a login time but no corresponding logout time?

Comment: Don't keep your `DateTime` values in character typed columns.

Comment: Ya i kept DateTime In Varchar. should i Make it in DateTime typed column.

Comment: This program includes two forms, 1 for login and other for Logout. But i dont know how to display both in single row in the database

Comment: Refer http://www.dotnetspark.com/Forum/3447-how-store-login-and-logout-time-into-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are inserting a new row each time.

You need to explore the Sql UPDATE statement.  Basically what you need to do is insert a new row on login and retrieve a unique identifier for that specific row.  When the user logs out you need to update that same row using the identifier and set the logout time accordingly.

Hope this points you in the right direction